# MVC5 Facebook get users photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a website app in MVC5 that allows a user to login using Facebook/Twitter.  Once they are logged in we will look through their photos for ones marked with a certain hashtag.

I have the login working for both FB and Twitter - and using Linq2Twitter I can get the and post photos.

However with Facebook I am having some problems.  My understanding with Facebook is that after the login I have to make a second call to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token in order to get a short lived access token.

However this call requires a "code" and a returnUri. I am unsure what this code is or how to get it, and what return URI to use.

My startup.Auth.cs looks like this

```
        var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_photos");
        facebookOptions.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppId"];
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"];

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

And everything logs in fine and I end back at ExternalLoginCallback

So where do I go from here.  How do I find this code and what returnUri do I use in order to get the access code.

Once I have this access code I plan to call (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/photos)

Hopefully I am going about this the correct way and my question makes sense

Many thanks.

Comment: Okay - I think I have a solution - this article explains how to do it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Okay - This solves my problem

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx